# Optimal buying strategy with multiple shops and items

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on a program to "optimally" buy magic cards. On the site each user has a "mini-shop", think eBay without the auctions.

The users enters a list of cards he wants to buy, I then fetch all offers from the site and print an "optimal" shopping list. Optimal meaning cheapest. Prices differ in the shops and also postage changes depending on how many cards you buy.

I would like to implement some algorithm which creates that list for me. I have written one, which works(I think), but I have no idea how good it works.

So my question is this: Can this problem be solved by some existing algorithm? It would need to deal with ~1000 offers for EACH card (normally 40-60 cards, so around 50k different offers)

Can somone point me in the correct direction on this?

Comment: _"I have written one, which works(I think), but I have no idea how good it works. "_ Does this mean, it returns results but you don't know if they are the best results? Or, it returns the best results, but you don't know if you implemented it in the fastest possible way?

Comment: @Kevin: I get a result, but I have no way of checking if it is the best one.

Comment: The algo is simple, price + shipping = totalprice... then sort by totalprice :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "partition" or "bin packing" problems (which are both mappable to what you want to do) is known to be NP-complete. Thus, the only way to make SURE that you have the optimal solution is to try all possible solutions and pick the best way.
If the user wants to buy 1,000 cards, trying all possible options is not computationally feasible, so you need to use heuristics.

Comment: "Knapsack problem" is another common name for this class of problems.

Comment: Thanks. I'll start my research with those two.